# not authorized for query on admin.system.users - first user created

Tags: mongodb

I have a sharded cluster on mongo (3 replica sets, each one with three nodes). All mongod`s are running with keyFile option.
To see all the users on the data base:

```
$ mongo --port XXXXX -u USER -p PASSWORD admin <br>
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.12<br>
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:XXXXX/admin<br>
mongos> use admin<br>
switched to db admin<br>
mongos> show users<br>
Tue Dec 16 01:46:17.763 error: { "$err" : "not authorized for query on   
admin.system.users", "code" : 16549 } at src/mongo/shell/query.js:128<br>mongos><br>
```

I think I wrongly created the first user administrator with not enough privileges. Is that so? How do I see the privileges of current mongo user? What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your user does not have necessary privileges.

- run mongod on localhost without `--auth`
- run [`db.getUser()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getUser/#db.getUser) or [`db.getRole()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getRole/#db.getRole) to verify user privileges
- grant the necessary [role](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#built-in-roles) to your user. Let say `clusterAdmin` role to your user using [`db.grantRolesToUser()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.grantRolesToUser/#db.grantRolesToUser)

`db.grantRolesToUser("username", [ { role : "clusterAdmin", db: "admin" } ] )`

**From mongodb documentation**:

> If users exist in the MongoDB database, but none of them has the appropriate prerequisites to create a new user or you do not have access to them, you must restart mongod with the --noauth option. [**First User Restrictions**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/#first-user-restrictions)

You may also need to read [**Enable Authentication in a Sharded Cluster**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication-in-sharded-cluster/#enable-authentication-in-a-sharded-cluster)

Comment: I'm running my mongod in a sharded cluster with --keyFile option. My question is: is it possible to add a superuser without shut down the entire replica set (since the first user I created is not superuser)?
If I do what you suggested above I do not have write access to admin database, since my instance is not running with keyFile and doesn't connect to the replica set and it's not primary.